# <a> hovering not working with child spans

Tags: css, hover, html

I have a problem I don't understand.

I'm creating an inbox, and I want the hovered message to change the background colour.

I am using spans to place the items, and I reckon this might be the reason that I cannot see any effect when hovering.

This is my css code:

```
#mainPanel #inbox h3 #fromSubjectHeader {
display: inline-block;
font-style:italic;
width: 177px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
}

#mainPanel #inbox h3 #dateHeader {
display:block;
font-style:italic;
width:177px;
text-align: left;
float:left;
}

#mainPanel #inbox a #fromSubject {
display: inline-block;
width: 173px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
padding-left: 4px;
}

#mainPanel #inbox a #date {
display:block;
width:173px;
text-align: left;
float:left;
padding-left: 4px;
}

#mainPanel #inbox a {
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
line-height: 16px;
width:535px;
}

#mainPanel #inbox a #unreadInbox {
font-weight:bold;
color:#165E8A;
}

#mainPanel #inbox a:hover { 
background:#B0DFF2; 
}
```

In the html code its called like this

```
<a>
<span id="fromSubject"></span>
<span id="fromSubject"></span>
<span id="date"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please share your code on http://jsbin.com so that we can see your problem live. Then post a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 1):

For each of the styles on the various spans set the `display` property to `inline-block` and remove the `float` property.  This will allow the `a` tag to expand to the height of its content.

```
#mainPanel #inbox a #fromSubject {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Rest of Styles */
}

#mainPanel #inbox a #date {
   display:inline-block;
   /* Rest of Styles */
}

#mainPanel #inbox a {
  display:inline-block;
  /* Rest of Styles */
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/Ns6ag/

Comment: @SimonMalone Glad I could help.  This is caused because the containers of floated block elements will not honor the actual height.  Instead the nested elements overflow the container, which has a height of 0.  You can read about clearfixes to see examples/solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply "clearfix" to `a` element, as all of it's content is floated and that results in `a` having 0 height.

If you do not know what clearfix is, take a look at [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working in FireFox and Crome but not in IE 
for that please put the below tag at top of the page

```
<!doctype html>
```